# Gaussian Elimination: 4 equations, 8 unknowns

Tags: gaussian-elimination

I need to find the solution set of all b=(b1,b2,b3,b4) element R^4 for this:

[image]

I know how Gaussian elimination works, but how do I find all possible solutions of all the b's?

Comment: Leave the right hand side as shown, in $b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4$. Start to do Gaussian elimination, and find the conditions where the $b$'s are not in contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the matrix $A$:

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -4 & 5 & 1 \\ 1 &-2 & 3 & 1\\ 7 & -11 & 18 & 7 \\ -2 & 3 & -5 &-2 \end{pmatrix}.$$

Notice how the first and last columns are the same? This means that the matrix is singular; in other words, its rank is less than its dimension. In fact, if you perform Gaussian elimination, you will find that its rank is 2 (try it!).

What does this mean?

Well, consider $A$ as a linear transformation. Since its rank is 2, and its dimension is 4, then the dimension of its null space is also 2. That means that when you apply this linear transformation to vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$, your result will either be zero, or it will lie in a 2-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. This means that $b$ is either a vector of zeros, or it lies in this subspace. Your task is to find a basis for this subspace, and then $b$ is any linear combination of those basis vectors. Since the subspace is 2-dimensional, you should find two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ forming the basis.

Comment: but I don't know the b's. The task reads that I need to find out the solution set of all b=(b1,b2,b3,b4)

Comment: Maybe type out the problem fully. As you have described it, it doesn't make for a very interesting problem.

Comment: Ah, I see why they're asking now. I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have. Full:
Determine the Set S of all b=(b1,b2,b3,b4) element R^4 for which the real system of linear equations above has solutions.

Comment: @user3071205 See my edit, hopefully that makes sense!

Comment: OK. So a basis for the subspace would be B={(1,0,1,1),(0,1,-1,0)}, wouldn't it? From here, how do I go about finding out the set of b1,b3,b3,b4?

Comment: Every vector in a subspace can be written as a linear combination of its basis vectors.